# Upload multiple attachments in a SharePoint list

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, office365

Is there a custom control available (JavaScript/Jquery) which will help attaching multiple files in a sharepoint list. OOTB SharePoint allows attaching one by one.

Yes, we can use: **$(".ms-fileinput").attr("multiple","multiple");** , though it only works once and gets back to one file at a time mode second time. My Browser is IE and looking for a solution that works on it, so "FILEREADER" solutions won't work.

I'll for sure keep this thread updated if I am able to find or work something out.